# How to handle a secondary task error that is crucial but primary task may only succeed once?

Tags: swift, firebase, error-handling

For example, I'm creating a new Firebase user, which runs async and on success, I then create a database reference for that user.

If the creation task succeeds, but then the secondary database writing fails, how should I handle this.  My app will crash if the user is logged in and tries accessing the database entry, but obviously I can't simply return an error when the write fails and restart all over with creating the same user and attempting database write again.

Comment: There are no transactions across multiple services in Firebase. If you have dependencies, you'll typically handle them by robust programming of your clients, and periodic scrubbing of your data. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028090/how-to-create-user-and-upload-data-on-firebase-in-one-single-transaction/43030853#43030853

Comment: Yes thank you this is the explanation I’m looking for!